# TFS 2017 Online code editor: print .md (markdown)

Tags: tfs

I found the possibility to create, edit and preview Markdown-Files in TFService.
Unfortunately, theres no way to print it out directly from the webpage.
Does anyone knows how to print such a file clean and with all the formatting in it?

Comment: As we discussed here, TFS code editor doesn't support print the markdown contents with multiple pages. So as a workaround we can only introduce the third markdown editors or extensions/plugs for now. Or you can submit a [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services) to suggest the feature. BTW, you can accept one of the replies which you think it's better to achieve your requirement as an answer. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There's a [suggestion](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31924270-print-or-create-pdf-from-markdown-within-online-co) on the User Voice on the Microsoft page.
- If the contents is not too long (within one page), then you can print
  it directly : (Chrome Browser for example)

  **Enter full screen mode** >> Then **`Ctrl + P`** to print the page
- If there are more than one pages, then you need to print with third
  editor, eg the **online Markdown Editor** :https://dillinger.io/

  1. Open the online editor https://dillinger.io/
  2. Copy the Markdown contents to the left area, preview in left area
  3. Select **Preview as** > Select a format eg, **PDF** or
     **StyledHtml**
  4. **`Crtl + P`** to print the file, it will print all the pages

---

**UPDATE:**

The TFS can print only one page of the Markdown contents. As a workaround, if you have local pictures/files embedded in the Markdown file, you can use the local editor. With the local editor you can freely do any actions you want. I find two better Markdown editors for you : [markdownpad](http://markdownpad.com/) and [West Wind Markdown Monster](https://markdownmonster.west-wind.com/download.aspx).

You can have a try for them.  **View in webpage (preview in web)** > `Ctrl+P` or export to PDF etc, then print.
[image]

Comment: This is a good solution. But there's one difficulty. If you have some pictures which are only local, you aren't able to print it with the dillinger tool. And to be honest, full screen mode doesn't make it look really good :-)

Comment: @Oswald Yeah, just as I mentioned above, select third Markdown editor based on your requirements. If you have local pictures, you can use the local editor, with the local editor you can freely do any actions you want. I find two better Markdown editors for you : [markdownpad](http://markdownpad.com/) and [West Wind Markdown Monster](https://markdownmonster.west-wind.com/download.aspx), you can have a try for them.

Answer (score 0):

I think i've found the least painful method for printing the Makrdown files including local images in it.

If you don't have any images, the solution of Andy-MSFT with [dillinger.io](https://dillinger.io/) is better.

To print with images, I use Visual Studio with the [Markdown Editor Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MarkdownEditor).
[image: Markdown Plugin]
There you have a "Print Preview" and some other good features.

Comment: @Andy-MSFT: what do you think about this solution?

Comment: yeah, there are lots of the third editors, the one you mentioned is  an plugin for VS. I also provide you the other two editors in below updated answer. Both of them are OK for preview or print.

Answer (score -1):

I confirm that the [Markdown Editor extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MarkdownEditor) of Visual Studio works great with the "Print Preview".

Another option, **but from Visual Studio and local files**, is a Chrome Extension, [Markdown Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-viewer/ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk?hl=en), which has a lot of options (parser, theme and content) and it is open source. You must allow the extension to access local file url in the settings.

They are better option from an online editor if you are working with sensitive data.

Comment: Are you shure that Markdown Viewer works with Team Foundation Service? It doesn't work with mine at all

Comment: I have edited my comment. It works fine from Visual Studio and local files but not directly from the online code editor of VSTS.

Comment: But that's exactly what I'm looking for :-)

Comment: You were also talking about Visual Studio extension and the chrome extension is another alternative or at least the best you can find... Sorry ;-)